# How to get the ID of the Current element clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I want to get the Value of the Current Element to be clicked.
I have a list of Checkboxes and selection of each I want to get the ID of it which is hidden.
My Code goes as follows:

```
$("#ModelListView").on("click", ".ModelCheckBox", function (element) {
    var AnalysisID = $("#AnalysisID").val();
    var ModelID = '';
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="ModelListView"></div>
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="Modeltemplate">
    <div class="section group fr">
        <div class="col span_2_of_12">
            #if(ACTIVE_MODELS_COUNT > 0){# <input class="ModelCheckBox" type="checkbox"  checked/>#} else {# <input class="ModelCheckBox" type="checkbox" unchecked/>  #}#
        </div>
        <div class="col span_4_of_12"><label>#:MODEL#</label></div>
        <input id="Model_ID" type="hidden" value=#:MODEL_ID#/>
    </div>
  </script>
```

I want to get the Value of Model_ID that is kept hidden.

Comment: var ModelID = $("#AnalysisID").attr('value');

Comment: use this `var ModelID = $(this).parent().next('#Model_ID').val()`

Comment: @guradio ,the Value is Undefined

Comment: Thank you..............  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` and get the closest.

`$(this)` will be the element that's clicked.

`.closest('.section.group')` will return the "`section group`"-div. You might want to use `#ModelListView` instead of .`section.group`.

`.find('#Model_ID').val()` will return the value of the hidden field.

```js
$("#ModelListView").on("click", ".ModelCheckBox", function (element) {
    var AnalysisID = $("#AnalysisID").val();
    var ModelID = $(this).closest('.section.group').find('#Model_ID').val();
    alert(ModelID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ModelListView">
    <div class="section group fr">
        <div class="col span_2_of_12">
            <input class="ModelCheckBox" type="checkbox"  checked/>
        </div>
        <div class="col span_4_of_12"><label>Label</label></div>
        <input id="Model_ID" type="hidden" value="someValue"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Sidenote: be aware of using an ID in a template.

Comment: Thanks Alot :) Now I have changed to Class="Model_ID"